# The possibility of a programming humor section?

Tags: feature-request

I have noticed that topics like this [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke) or [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered) are now frowned upon however I, like many people enjoy such topics and wish for the possibility of more such content with a similar nature.

I understand that the group of people who actually run the site however appear not to value these wonderful topics that provide lots of enjoyment to many programmer's lives.

I also understand that if the "rulers" of stackoverflow don't want the humor on stackoverflow, it is there site and they are going to do whatever they please however keeping the best interests of the users in mind helps keep people coming back and hence more ad revenue.

I think to compensate for the fact that humor is not wanted on stackoverflow, we should create a different section or site most likely on stack exchange or maybe a subdomain or stackoverflow. I think humoroverflow or humorexchange would be a good name for such a place or simply programminghumor or if a subdomain of stackoverflow just simply humor.stackoverflow.com. Whatever works best for the admins of this site.

If you are reading this and thinking of please no don't do it, could you please explain why or if you are responsible for the attack on humor could you explain why you did that?

If you are in favor of this I understand that you maybe thinking something to the effect of "I am just one person how I can I make a difference". The answer to that is to let your voice and your vote be seen. The more expressed support the higher chance we have of getting such a thing done and remember your voice and your vote do matter. One vote or comment may be small but with all votes and comments combined we will make a difference. If everyone adopted the I am only one vote mentality not much would get done.

Comment: It has nothing to do with humor being frowned upon and everything to do with it being an unconstructive mess of random things. They tried an "off-topic" site like that before, and it failed (eventually redefined into what is now Programmers SE).

Comment: @animuson unconstructive in what sense? Those topic achieve a goal of providing high quality humor which I do think many members value. I do not believe it to be a mess of random things as those are on topic. For example the programming jokes topic has jokes that relate to programming and the "best" comments topic has funny comments that programmers have encountered or created. As for the off-topic site why did it fail?

Comment: I'm confused what you find constructive about a 21-page list of random jokes. Interesting, yes. Constructive, no. That's like saying all the employees standing around the water cooler gossiping for an hour is being constructive. I'm sure their boss would disagree.

Comment: @user3462295: see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144) for the sad history of the site "Not Programming Related"

Comment: You could always [propose such a site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), but I don't hold out much hope for success. A Q&A format isn't great for that kind of content.

Comment: @animuson No the goal of this is not be something that people can do instead of work. I think it is nice for example after a long day of programming to come home and read some humor to lighten the load of the day so to say.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I am suggesting a site that is related to programming. That site is specifically named "NOT programming related"

Comment: @AlE. I was not aware of such feature. I will give this thread some time and based on the outcome of this thread consider weather or not I should submit a request.

Comment: @user3462295 Not Programming Related was often used, in practice, for programming-related humorous questions that didn't meet the needs of the main site. This was much of the reason for its downfall (please read the linked answer)

Comment: I don't even think there would be enough content to populate such a site. Programmer humor is a pretty narrow topic, and we only ever had a small handful of such questions here. Plus, doesn't Reddit pretty much cover your humor needs in one place, programming-related or not?

Comment: Already exists: http://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/

Comment: @CodyGray in a fit of recursion I give you [How do I get a static IP for my teapot?](http://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/2dl1gx/how_do_i_get_a_static_ip_for_my_teapot/)... now, if we can somehow work a humorous answer there that points here...

Answer (score 7):

SO is Q&A. What's the Q&A for jokes? Would the question be "Knock, knock" several hundred times? Are you sure you're not just asking the SE development team to create an unrelated product with a lot of effort for your entertainment? Don't be surprised if they say no. How are you not just describing Reddit? Since you are just describing Reddit, why do you think StackExchange should randomly drop what it's doing to try to compete with Reddit? Do you think that StackExchange has some brand name advantage or something? If so, do you plan to call the new site "StackOverflow: The Water Cooler" or something? Am I going to start getting in trouble for using SO at work since my boss now knows it's half just a time-wasting wing?

In short: I'm not sure you've thought this through. See the Area 51 proposals for some guidelines on what a beta SE site would look like. Note most Area 51 proposals fail. It's a hard job.

Comment: I am suggesting an extension to stackoverflow not a change in what stackoverflow itself is, and I do say that the stackoverflow site format is superior to Reddit given the way that thoughts are organized. This allows for a better discussion of humor. I admit that I very rarely visit Reddit. I think you missed the point that for the most part this would not be the same stackoverflow. It is a separate place for those that want humor, so that they can take it there instead of at stackoverflow where such humor is not wanted. This would most likely be a sub-site of stackexchange.

Comment: If you are wondering what I mean by the superior format that stackoverflow features, you see on stackoverflow the main though is created by the OP and each response is a branch on the "tree" if you will, based upon the OP's topic. People can create branches on the branches so to say when responding to an answer to the topic for example I created a branch on your branch of this topic. I believe that this organization is good for a humor website and quite frankly I just like it from the perspective of the way stackoverflow functions it is good, and works very well for Q&A and beyond.

Comment: @user3462295 SO is not a "tree". Each object is a structure consisting of a question, and an array of answers. I'm not sure where you get the idea that the branches are branching out, or why humor is every discussed in such intricate detail unless you're an anthropologist studying humor (and therefore not partaking in it).

Comment: @user3462295 so yes I think your premise is completely absurd that humor is best read over an arcane Q&A system.